# Symfony LexikMaintenanceBundle - The service "lexik_maintenance.driver.factory" has a dependency on a non-ex istent service "translator.default"

Tags: php, symfony-3.4, maintenance-mode

I am using symfony 3.4 version. I have installed "LexikMaintenanceBundle" by referring [this](https://github.com/lexik/LexikMaintenanceBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md). 
I have done configurations as same as the documentations. When I run the command

> "php bin/console lexik:maintenance:lock"

I got this error

> "The service "lexik_maintenance.driver.factory" has a dependency on a non-ex
>         istent service "translator.default".".

Any idea to overcome from this problem ?

Comment: Have you registred the translator service : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/translation.html#translation-configuration in config.yml ?

Comment: Thank you so much. The line "translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }" was commented in config.yml. After uncommenting it worked for me.